# Date is varchar, convert to float in order to take average date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, varchar

My dates are varchar(50) and appear like this in my database:

> 2/15/2012

The table looks like this: (Note: someid is not a primary key, its identifies a group)

```
 |  someid  |   date     |  float_value  | 
 |   1      | 2/15/2012  |     3.2       |   
 |   1      | 2/15/2012  |     1.4       |
 |   1      | 2/15/2012  |     2.1       |
 |   1      | 2/16/2012  |     1.8       |
```

How would I do something like this:

```
select avg(date), avg(float_value)
where someid = 1
```

To return something like this:

```
|  date     |  float_value  |
| 2/15/2012 |   2.126       |
```

Perhaps the answer isn't average date, but like the date the occurs the most often (in terms of the someid).

Any help would be appreciated from the sql experts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First convert the date filed to date - what happens if a date filed cannot be converted to a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the float nonsense. How about:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, create_date)), 0) FROM sys.objects;
```

In your case you'll need to convert first. E.g.

```
SELECT 
  avg_date = DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [date]))), 0) 
FROM dbo.yourtable
WHERE someid = 1;
```

This variation may also be useful:

```
SELECT 
  someid, 
  avg_date = DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [date]))), 0) 
FROM dbo.yourtable
GROUP BY someid;
```

**EDIT** to present the exact precise and particular formatting that seems to be necessary:

```
SELECT 
  avg_date = CONVERT(CHAR(10), 
    DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [date]))), 0),
    101) 
FROM dbo.yourtable
WHERE someid = 1;
```

Comment: - Well I think it was mainly because I was doing a bulk insert, and I don't want to have my date column having '00:00:00' in every row.  I'm not aware that you can have just a date type in sql server 2005

Comment: @akwarywo datetime values are not *stored* that way, this is just how the data is presented to you in, say, Management Studio. Don't use the wrong data type for the wrong reason. Also, I never suggested to use a `DATE` data type. In SQL Server 2005 you should be using `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME`.

Comment: We're close with that query, quick question: whats the difference between smalldatetime and datetime. Also the query is close, but it still returns date in the form:  
    2012-02-15 00:00:00.000

Comment: That is just formatting. You can use CONVERT(CHAR(10), expression, 101), but can't your client application format it the way you want it?

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much for your time and expertise.  (sorry for being picky)